# Java script function minimise

Tags: javascript, function

I have simple open/close code for my item and want to add it to my next 2 items at the same page (called item__description2 with description-btn2 and item__description3 with description-btn3), but I don't want to create new functions for every item! Is there any way to make it in 1 function for all items?

```
function openFunction() {
let x = document.getElementById("item__description");
let element = document.getElementById("description-btn");

if (x.className === "item__description") {
    x.className += "-responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "item__description";
}
```

}

Comment: You know you can pass parameters to functions ..?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass parameters to the function.

```
function openFunction(itemID, itemDescription) {
let x = document.getElementById(itemID);
let element = document.getElementById(itemDescription);

if (x.className === itemID) {
    x.className += "-responsive";
} else {
    x.className = itemID;
}
```